# How do you detect the Windows XPe shutdown reason in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-xp-embedded, shutdown-hook

I'm correctly intercepting the Windows shutdown message *WMQueryEndSession* in Delphi 2009 with the following procedure:

```
procedure TMyForm.WMQueryEndSession(var msg: TMessage);
```

This article suggests that I can distinguish between a regular shutdown and a log off by examining the *LParam* of message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Update:**

I'm developing an application to run on *Windows XP Embedded*, and in my case, the *LParam* is 0 every time however.

If I test my application under Windows 7 or Windows XP Home then I get the expected $80000000.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: code?  What value type are you using to read the LParam?

Comment: Does your App use some COM interface ? Probe the box using a bare Delphi App to see wether the unexpected weird behaviour keep persisting.

Comment: Is it possible that some other app on your system is setting lparam to zero before the message reaches you?